# Undefined var error in an array iteration on a page using mootools

Tags: javascript, arrays, mootools

```
 var makeModelYearSelect = document.getElementById("<%= MakeModelYearFilterLB.ClientID %>").control;
 var selectedMakeModelYearItems = makeModelYearSelect.get_checkedItems();
 var selectedMakeModelYearItemIds = [];


 for (var index = 0; index < selectedMakeModelYearItems.length; index++) {
   selectedMakeModelYearItemIds.push(selectedMakeModelYearItem[index].get_value(index));
 }
```

Why is this firing back an error of `Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'selectedMakeModelYearItem' is undefined`?

Mootools won't let me use a simple for...in for iterations.

I've looked at it 6 ways to Sunday so what the heck am I missing?

Comment: This is your one-time-only typo identification service from me!

Comment: BTW IMO this is the preferred array iteration technique so don't worry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `selectedMakeModelYearItem` is undefined.

`selectedMakeModelYearItems` isn't, though.

Comment: Hmm, a downvote for the correct answer. That's interesting.

Comment: thanks...and I feel stupid now...lol

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you try to call this code berofe page is loaded. In this case select tag that you try to access don't rendered and cannot be accessed from JavaScript. You can try something like

```
window.addEventListener("load",
(function() {
return function setMakeModelYearFilter() {
        var makeModelYearSelect = document.getElementById("<%= MakeModelYearFilterLB.ClientID %>").control;
        var selectedMakeModelYearItems = makeModelYearSelect.get_checkedItems();
        var selectedMakeModelYearItemIds = [];


for (var index = 0; index < selectedMakeModelYearItems.length; index++) {
   selectedMakeModelYearItemIds.push(selectedMakeModelYearItem[index].get_value(index));
}
    window.removeEventListener('load', setMakeModelYearFilter, false);
}})()
, false);
```

Comment: `selectedMakeModelYearItem` is a variable that wasn't defined, not a DOM element that couldn't be found.

Comment: makeModelYearSelect.get_checkedItems(); may be this depends from DOM object that is not loaded. I'm not sure.